# How can I revert all open files in perforce?

Tags: version-control, perforce

I know how to revert a single opened file. However sometimes I hit some issues where I have to revert all files attached in a single changelist or revert all open pending files (default CL or assigned CL) in a client. Is there any way to do that? I tried `p4 revert -c <changelist>` where  has multiple pending files. It didn't work for me. It works if I mention ALL the file names.

Comment: What error did you get with revert -c ?

Comment: Please avoid unnecessary tags. I am removing `git` as this has nothing at all to do with it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I bet you just need to provide a filespec, try `p4 revert -c <changelist> //...`

Answer (score 28):

For me the following worked as well

```
p4 revert //... : Revert every file you have open, in every one of your pending changelists, to its pre-opened state.
```

or

```
p4 revert -c default //... : Revert every file open in the default changelist to its pre-opened state
```

Taken from : [p4 revert documentation](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r12.1/manuals/cmdref/revert.html)

Answer (score 14):

On linux

p4 opened | sed 's/#.*//g' | xargs -n 1 p4 revert

Comment: God, you are a life savor

Answer (score 1):

Slight updated in the answer of @Talespin_Kit

Below one takes care of files that have spaces in their name

$p4 opened | sed 's/#.*//g' | xargs -n 1 p4 -d '\n' revert

Comment: I think you've put `-d '\n'`in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

When I try to run the command from the accepted answer

```
p4 revert -c <<changelist>>
```

I get the error:

> Usage: revert [ -a -n -k -w -c changelist# -C client ] [--remote=rmt]
> files... Missing/wrong number of arguments.

What I had to do was add the file name at the end of the command like so

```
p4 revert -c <<changelist>> //depot/folder/folder/file.txt
```